# Sharing iCloud Core Data between iOS and OS X

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, icloud

I should work on a project both for iOS and OS X. Obviously i have 2 different projects and my question is: should the 2 projects have the same xcdatamodeld to share Core Data via iCloud? Meaning same structure or exactly same (name + structure)? I'm still at the beginning of the OS X app and would like to know in advance if i have to import the iOS core data file or i can create another one.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Regarding this subject, do you need to be enrolled in both iOS and Mac OS X Developer programs in order to share data via iCloud?

Comment: You do for iOS, since you need to test on a real device to access iCloud. I assume this is also for OS X but I'm not sure since the simulator is already you system. This problem I had was for homework at U, so I didn't test further on the subject I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should the 2 projects have the same xcdatamodeld to share Core Data via iCloud?

If you want to share data stores between the two projects, then yes. Use the same model file in both projects.

It's not uncommon to build a model for an iOS project and then to use the same model file in a simple OS X project so that you can easily examine or modify the data from a MacOS X app.

Comment: Just an extra caution: be careful of any class that does not exist on both platforms. Eg. Don't put NSColor in a transformable property, and don't store NSAttributedStrings. Store platform independent values like rgba values. You can either implement a model-attached NSValueTransformer class differently for each platform, or just convert the values to native objects in your model class.